# When anonymizing user data, is pseudo-random good enough?

Tags: php, security

I'm building a system that holds student records.  To minimize the affect of potential data breaches, and reduce the work required for Freedom of Information requests, we are anonymizing all user accounts after a period of time.

One of the steps I'm taking to anonymizing user accounts is to replace the username with `__anon__` + 12 random characters.

From a security perspective, can I just use PHP's `*_rand()` functions or do I have to use something more cryptographically appropriate?

I don't think the `*_rand()` functions could create an anonymous random string that could somehow be used to identify the account information with the original username - but I thought I'd ask SO in case I'm missing something.

Comment: replacing username is all fine and dandy, but if this user data is something like forum posts, and your DB has `anon1234 replied to anon5678` and the message contains "Hey, [realusername], wake up", the anonymisation is for naught.

Comment: I'd rather go with `_anon_[timestamp][randchars]` just to avoid possibility of duplicates. that way you don't need 12 random characters, 3 or 4 would be enough. To save space you can convert timestamp to hexadecimal.

Comment: Depends on how anonymous you want it to be, if you persistently set a value against a user and *output it to others* the its not anonymous anyway, Id do what SO does and assign the user there corresponding row id against there name `anon251859`<<your id, but then its not anonymous. Tobe anonymous just dont **output** there name if they have a flag you set in db or such, or call everyone `anonymous`

Comment: @MarcB This isn't for data that users can freely affect.  Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 Adding a timestamp would associate real-world information with the account, which could be used to at least narrow down who the account was originally for.

Comment: @Pickle, Sure, I agree. I mentioned timestamp just as a way to make unique names with no need to check if that already exists. If you really want to make something high secure and still keep in touch with original account user, you have to do more complicated job. For example, in banking software we're using at work, user-auth and user-secure scripts at server have approx. 40MB of pure code (in total). Course, that doesn't mean you have to do the same job, it just depends of purpose and what level of security you want to achieve.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 The anonymizing code isn't user facing, and would probably affect at most 50 users at a time, so I'm just going to check pre-existence in a loop.  Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter how random `rand` or any other function really is. The point is that you are replacing the actual name with another name, and this new name is derived via a method which has absolutely nothing to do with the original name. In other words, you're not using the original name as input to your `rand` function, so there's nothing connecting the original with the new pseudo random name. You could be using an incrementing counter for each user, it would have the same effect of disconnecting the original name from the new replacement.

You should of course be using the best PRNG available on the system, which is typically `/dev/random` on *NIX systems. But in order for anyone to connect even a badly randomly generated string with any other data, there'd have to be some connection. Say, if an attacker knew your precise method and time of when you anonymise what data and in what order and the attacker also knows the original data that you are anonymising, it would be theoretically possible to connect a randomly generated name with the original known data. But that's extremely theoretical and probably irrelevant in practice.

Comment: I am anonymizing all user accounts older than 5 years.  So the order in which the accounts get anonymized will be roughly the same as the order in which they were created.  Still, that shouldn't be a problem should it?

Comment: An attacker would need a lot of information about the state of the system at the time you do the anonymizing; any flaw would be virtually only theoretical I'd think.